# Canvas, instead of image, reacts on routed event

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-events, pdftron

I have an application using WPF, Caliburn and PDF tron. It draws image pages and alows brosing through them. Browsing can be done several ways, by specific button or by hitting particular canavas area. Part of drawn area are small icons for active content (web links, images and so on). These icons are animated when they detec mouse on them. When I move to next or previous page, by anything else than canavas hit area, everything i fine. When i try canavas area, the icons stop working. They start work once i switch to another window (which makes it annyingly difficult to debug as visual studio is the other window), or when i click anywhere on the application window. I have been debugging this and it seems that event which handles animation is never routed to the icon, and icon is never aware of fact that mouse is over it. Only canavas gets the notification. Could somone please advise solution or proper methodology of troubleshooting?

(code follows)

Drawing icon function:

```
public LinkIcon DrawInteractivityIcon(ICensoredNameLinkIconable link)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Drawing Icon on canvas");
            LinkIcon icon = new LinkIcon(link);
            icon.Width = Defaults.CensoredNameIconSize;
            icon.Height = Defaults.CensoredNameIconSize;
            icon.Effect = new DropShadowEffect
            {
                Color = Colors.Gray,
                BlurRadius = Defaults.CensoredNameIconSize / 3 * GetZoom(),
                Opacity = 0.5,
                ShadowDepth = Defaults.CensoredNameIconSize / 7d * GetZoom()
            };

            icon.SetValue(Panel.ZIndexProperty, 210);

            if (link is ICensoredNameLinkTextInfoable)
            {
                ICensoredNameLinkTextInfoable textinfoLink = link as ICensoredNameLinkTextInfoable;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(textinfoLink.TextInfo);
                if (link is ICensoredNameExpandable)
                {
                    ICensoredNameExpandable expandableLink = link as ICensoredNameLinkExpandable;
                    foreach (ICensoredNameLinkTextInfoable tiLink in expandableLink.AddedLinks.OfType<ICensoredNameLinkTextInfoable>())
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine();
                        sb.Append(tiLink.TextInfo);
                    }
                }
                icon.ToolTip = sb.ToString();
            }

            AddElementToCanvas(icon, 0);

            UpdateCanvasElement(icon, link.IconPosition, link.Page);

            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Is icon hitVisible?: {0}", icon.IsHitTestVisible.ToString()));


            return icon;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Called from here:
(drawing icons, binding event delegates)

```
private LinkIcon DrawInteractivityIcon(ICensoredNameLinkIconable link)
    {
        try
        {
            LinkIcon icon = PDFViewer.DrawInteractivityIcon(link);

            icon.MouseEnter += Icon_MouseEnter;
            icon.MouseLeave += Icon_MouseLeave;
            icon.MouseLeftButtonDown += Icon_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            icon.MouseRightButtonDown += Icon_MouseRightButtonDown;
            Debug.WriteLine("Creating icon, binding delegates"); // TODO Clear before going to production

            icon.MouseMove += Icon_MouseMove;
            icon.MouseLeftButtonUp += Icon_MouseLeftButtonUp;

            icon.LongTouch += Icon_LongTouch;

            icon.TouchDown += Icon_TouchDown;
            icon.TouchMove += Icon_TouchMove;
            icon.TouchUp += Icon_TouchUp;
            icon.TouchEnter += Icon_TouchEnter;
            icon.TouchLeave += Icon_TouchLeave;

            return icon;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogService.LogMessageToXml("Draw icon exception: " + ex.Message, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The icon class itself, inherited from image

```
public class LinkIcon : Image
{ <....probably nothing interesting except inheritance... >}
```

The delegate controling animation:

```
    private void Icon_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Calling Mouse Move! Move Mouse move! at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString()) );  //TODO clear beore going to production
        System.Windows.Point currentPosition = e.GetPosition(this.PDFViewer);          
        if (_movingElement != null)
        {
            if (PDFViewer.ReaderMode == ReaderModes.CustomInteractivity)
            {
                if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                {
                    PDFViewer.MoveElementToPoint(_movingElement, currentPosition);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Functions output to debug when working correctly:
Canvas-OnMOuseMove, Entering function 14.9.2016 14:48:19
Calling Mouse Move! Move Mouse move! at 14.9.2016 14:48:19
Canvas-OnMOuseMove, Entering function 14.9.2016 14:48:19
Canvas-OnMOuseMove, Entering function 14.9.2016 14:48:19
Canvas-OnMOuseMove, Entering function 14.9.2016 14:48:19

Comment: Functions output to debug when working incorrectly:
Canvas-OnMOuseMove, Entering function 14.9.2016 14:49:31
Canvas-OnMOuseMove, Entering function 14.9.2016 14:49:31
Canvas-OnMOuseMove, Entering function 14.9.2016 14:49:31
Canvas-OnMOuseMove, Entering function 14.9.2016 14:49:31

Comment: We reviewed your question, but there was not enough information to diagnose. In particular this was tagged with pdftron, but I don't see any PDFNet API usage. Though, based on what was posted so far, two suggestions. 1. Pointer capture lingering from pressing something on the old canvas, preventing other elements from observing the mouse moving.

2. Somehow, the new view isn't HitTestVisible or enabled as a result of changing the page.

Beyond that, you might want to review the PDFViewCtrl demo that comes with the SDK, and see how interaction/customization works.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. i will have a look. PdfTron is related through inheritance of     " PDFViewerTouch : pdftron.PDF.PDFViewWPF, INotifyPropertyChanged "this is class where first drawInteractivity function is located. Essenitialy the hit area i am using is lovcated on pefTron dranw image. From other testing, i assume option 1 lingering pointer capture, but i havn't been able to find what is causing it.